# How to resolve conflict when generating a xsd to jaxb objects

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

How to resolve conflict when generating a `xsd` to `jaxb` objects?

Below is example:

`A.xsd` includes `B.xsd` and `C.xsd`
Both `B.xsd` and `C.xsd` have a duplicate element

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options i have found to solve this issue when i ran into it not too long ago:

1. Rename the class in the XSD to something else to avoid the issue.
2. Creating a Binding File to remap the classes on generation.
3. Generate the classes from the bottom up making episode files and
   specifying a new package each time so that the objects do not clash
   within the same package.